# Expdp command will not export my table in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, datapump

I am trying to export a schema which only contains one table with one row on it. It has a table called "product" and resides in a tablespace called "tbs_data". Here's the expdp command I ran which completed successfully.

expdp dbauser/dbapasw@oradev schemas=myschema directory=my_data_pump_directory dumpfile=myschema_exp.dmp logfile=myschema_exp.log

I ran the impdp commmand and it completed w/o errors.  I then logged in and checked but didn't find the "product" table.  So I then reviewed the impdp log file.  I didn't see a line which reads "Exported product ...".  I tried adding 10,000 more rows to the table and repeated the expdp/impdp commands.  The table is still not being exported.

Can anyone tell me why??

Thanks

Comment: If you connect to `dbauser/dbapasw@oradev` and do `desc myschema.product` does it show the table as expected? Possibilities include that the table is in a different schema (check `dba_tables`), or a different database - particularly if you're connecting to the root container and the schema/table is in a PDB, perhaps. If it where you think what does the export log actually say?

Comment: Yes, it shows me this:                                                                                        Name      Null Type       
--------- ---- ---------- 
PRODUCTID      NUMBER(38)

Comment: here's the actual export log

Comment: Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 0 KB
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/STATISTICS/MARKER
Master table "dbauser"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded

Comment: I wasn't able to paste the entire log so I pasted what's pertinent here.  Sorry

Comment: You should edit the question to add new info, especially things that are large and/or need to be formatted.

Comment: Looks like that log does not show any objects being exported; so the schema being exported has no tables.

Comment: Run "select owner, object_type, object_name, status from dba_objects where object_name = 'PRODUCT'" . Start there to see if the PRODUCT "table" is actually a table or view, or materialised view.  Try exporting just the product table, use exp rather than expdp, then try expdp.  Check the alert log in case there was a hidden error in processing th etable.

Comment: It appears my issue may have something to do with the pluggable database in Oracle 12c.  I don't exactly know how this works yet but this is what I did over the weekend to make my expdp/impdb work.  I created two brand new VM's and installed Oracle 12c WITHOUT the pluggable database option checked.  So I have a source vm and a target vm.  I re-created the Product table on the source.  Ran expdp to create the dmp file.  Logged on to the target and ran impdp.using the dump created from the source.  Everything worked as expected!  I saw the Product table on the target.

Comment: So what is it that I need to do in order to run the expdb/impdb successfully when the Oracle instances were installed with the pluggable option checked?